# Problem with streaming audio in mobile with Android 9 version?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, react-native

I was making an app in react-native where I had to stream audio from a http (non secure) url. The app works well in debug mode but when I tried using the release version the audio didn't play in phones having Android 9 and above. I am using [this Library](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player).

I can't create the SSL for the link. Also I have tried with some SSL secure links (https) the library works fine with Secure Links, but due to certain restrictions I have to use the http link only.

Note: The audio streams well in Android 8 and below. I have tried using a WebView to play the audio didn't work.

Update:

1: Get yourself a https link for streaming your audio.

( If you can't do that )

2: Host up a proxy audio streaming server with your non secure http link

Keep coding